# How to create only binding not null controls in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I`d like select between combobox and textbox depending on ViewModel. In the view model i have two properties one of them should be null and the other not null.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqgIz.png)

Comment: You need to give some code example to help you. For starter go through DataTemplate to load different controls for different types(i.e. ViewModel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not sure if that´s exactly what you want to do. As CarbineCoder already said, some more code would be helpful. If you want to show only one of both controls you could create two properties called for example tbVisibility and cbVisibility. If you want to show the ComboBox, then cbVisibility has to be "visible" and tbVisibility has to be "hidden".

XAML would like that:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <!--This is visible if tbVisibility is "visible" and cbVisibility is "hidden"-->
            <Label Width="100" Content="label" Visibility="{Binding tbVisibility}"></Label>
            <TextBox Width="184" Text="Textbox" Visibility="{Binding tbVisibility}"></TextBox>

            <!--This part is visible if cbVisibility is "visible" and tbVisibility is "hidden"-->
            <Label Width="100" Content="label" Visibility="{Binding cbVisibility}"></Label>
            <TextBox Width="184" Visibility="{Binding cbVisibility}"></TextBox>

        </StackPanel>
```

You only have to define in you code which property is visibile and which is not.

Comment: This can work, but i have a question: if i use visibility every stackpanel would have would have all control and i only would be hiding some of them?

Comment: Yes the controles would still be there. Some of them would be visible and the others would be hidden. But they would still be there.